# icon=Graph in attachment2

Tags: hyperref, attachfile, hypdvips

Is there any way to add the graph icon of hypdvips package to the attachment2 package 
Otherwise some features of hypdvips are very nice, is there any way to add the possibility to use it in pdflatex? ;)

Maybe any idee exists for the first approach.

LG Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Own icons may be added to the package.

I am not aware how to add the code without modifying the attachfile2.sty but the solution is enough for me.

Best regards

Peter